# Large database on ios app, which needs monthly updates - best strategy

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

I've producing an iPad app which will display calculations obtained from a database of 800k records, provided in csv format. Its contents will be updated monthly and somehow loaded into the app each month.

The app is for a business, not for public, and so does not need to go through app store approval

What is the best strategy to efficiently work with data and also update it?

Option 1: Pre-process csv file into coredata entities on mac, place on server, then have app download and load in monthly;
Disadvantages: Pre processing csv in test macOS app took too long (days). Also can I replace the current coredata file easily on the fly, or tell app to look in another location once downloaded?

Option 2: Pre process on win server (if possible), into sqlite form and load into app;
Disadvantages: I understand latest coredata may be more efficient when large number of records(?).

Option 3: Update entire app with coredata embedded each month;
Disadvantages: Seems a bit of an overkill. I'd also have to be involved each month.

Option 4: ?

Be grateful for any ideas/pointers.

Comment: I think option 1 is best, but I am surprised that it took so long.  You should be able to load a batch of entries, parse them, save them and then load the next batch.  If you tried to to it all in one batch it might get stuck. How large is each entry?

Comment: Each row of the 800k is only about 30 strings, but I parse it and split it into various entities to reduce repetition. I must correct that my test was run in the ios simulator and was not a macos app which wouldn't have helped. Not sure preprocessing on a mac can be easily automated by my client though anyway - not even sure they have macs. All the entries need replacing monthly, not a just a subset. If pre-processing can be speeded up, can the coredata files in the app be overwritten with a download? If preprocessing take too long, is there any other way?

Comment: Converting directly to a SQLite database in a format that Core Data can use isn't a good idea, since that format is not documented by Apple and could change at any time. Maybe we can help you optimize the code you're using to transform the data? Have you run the transform in Instruments to identify what is taking so long?

Comment: Hi. I wasn't going to transfer between the two - use core data or sqlite. It seems core data has more positive comments of late, so looks the way to go. My concern with going further down this route is that the client hasn't macs to do this pre-processing, only iPads for the app, so how do I automate it each month when they product their csv file?